# How to use streams efficiently

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I improve my code using streams?

I have a `Map<Owner,  List<Car>>` as `ownerMap`. My `Car` class has the `getColor()` and `getPrice()` methods.

I want to write all the prices of the cars which have **red** color into a file.

This is my code so far:

```java
ownerMap.values().forEach((c) -> {
    if (c.iterator().hasNext() && c.iterator().next().getColor() == Color.RED) {
        // write to file
        ow.out(c.iterator().next().getPrice().toString() + "\n", output);
    }
}
```

The code is working, but how could I improve using stream methods? Please tell me whether my code solution is good or at which point it could be optimized.

Comment: Have a look at the use of stream filters which will allow you to filter in RED values within your map values

Comment: You can also stream the lists of cars:   `map.values().stream().forEach(e -> e.stream().filter(e -> e.getColor().equals(Color.RED)).forEach(c -> ow.out(c.getPrice().toString() + "\n", output)));`

Comment: “the code is working”… I don’t think so. You are never processing more than the first `List` element.

Comment: You have right. Thanks. Stream is not easy for me yet :/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Edit:

Sorry, there was an error in the `forEach()` call in the solution. I have corrected it now. There was no need to call `c.iterator()`.

---

I would go with M. S.'s solution. However, here is another version:

```
ownerMap.values().forEach( cl -> 
/* Filter the list based Color.RED */
cl.stream().filter( c -> c.getColor() == Color.RED)
/* Print each */
.forEach( c -> ow.out( c.getPrise().toString() + "\n", output ) ) );
```

Comment: Nested lambda's are very difficult to read and should be avoided. You should consider using flatMap (and map when relevant) to create a stream of items you want to iterate over. A stream<car> in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```java
ownerMap.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(car -> car.getColor() == Color.RED)
    .forEach(car -> ow.out(car.getPrise().toString() + "\n", output));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You could also point out collecting the data using groupingBy, or returning the filtered stream to allow the caller to collect the data as needed. Also, add an explaination so the user understand why to use flatMap over map on his stream of List<Car>.